# Ballistic trajectory. Find direction of cannon to make projectile reach the player

Tags: gravity

The problem is two-dimensional. I'm trying to make cannon aim at the player.
the cannon's projectile is pulled down by gravity, so the cannon should aim a bit higher, to hit the player.

**Input:**

- Player's x position relative to cannon
- Player's y position relative to cannon
- gravity g (negative number)
- Initial velocity of projectile

**I want to find:**

- If the player is in in the cannon's range
- If yes:

  - The direction at which projectile should be launched. Direction can be formed by a vector (x,y), such that x^2+y^2=1.

I was trying to solve this using some kinematic equations, but I always get stuck.

EDIT:
Here's some equations I got to:
**g**(gravity)
**x**(position x of the player)
**y**(position y of the player)
**v1**(initial velocity x)
**v2**(initial velocity y)
**t1**(time to fly up)
**t2**(time to fly down)
**h**(height of the ark)

```
v1 = (t1 + t2)/x  
v2 = sqrt(1 - v1^2)  
t1 = (-sqrt(v2))/g  
t2 = sqrt((2h - y)/g)  
h = -v2^2/2g
```

Comment: It would be helpful for others to know what work you have done already on this problem. Ideally post the formulae and code you've been working with.

Comment: Show some of your work, would you? This is not a "get your work done by others" website :)

Comment: Maybe consider mathoverflow instead?

Comment: This is more like a physics question. But we can still help.

Comment: oh, i didn't know there was "mathoverflow", but i found some crappy math forums and decided i'd try it here first, because i hate registering to more websites, than necessary

Comment: `v1 = cos(angle)v` and `v2 = sin(angle)v`.  I wouldn't split time up `t1` and `t2` because you need the full path.  you know that the x component of velocity is constant once fired.

Comment: thx, for idea Felix Castor, i'll keep trying

Comment: @Tuan333 and Villfuk02: Please do NOT post this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) which is for [research level math questions only](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I wrote some javascript code that does what you want:

```html
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="180"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
      var player_pos_x = 50;
      var player_pos_y = 100;
      
      var cannon_pos_x = 450;
      var cannon_pos_y = 150;
      
      var rel_x = player_pos_x - cannon_pos_x;
      var rel_y = player_pos_y - cannon_pos_y;

      var init_v = 700;
      
      var g = 1000.0;
                
      var trajectory = -1;//try also +1
      
      var a = g * g / 4.0;
      var b = - rel_y * g - init_v * init_v;
      var c = rel_x * rel_x + rel_y * rel_y;
      var D = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
      
      if (D < 0)
      {
       console.log("Not reachable");
        D = 0;
      }
      
      var t_square = (-b + trajectory * Math.sqrt(D))  / 2 / a;
            
      var t = Math.sqrt(t_square);
            
      var v_x = rel_x / t;
      var v_y = rel_y / t - g * t / 2.0;
      
      var dir_x = v_x / Math.sqrt(v_x * v_x + v_y * v_y);
      var dir_y = v_y / Math.sqrt(v_x * v_x + v_y * v_y);
      
      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
      }
   
      function render() {
        var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        var time = seconds % t;
        
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
       draw_circle(player_pos_x,player_pos_y, 7);
       draw_circle(cannon_pos_x,cannon_pos_y, 7);
        
       draw_circle(cannon_pos_x + init_v * dir_x * time, cannon_pos_y + init_v * dir_y * time + g * time * time / 2.0, 3);
        
        draw_line(cannon_pos_x, cannon_pos_y, cannon_pos_x + dir_x * 20, cannon_pos_y + dir_y * 20);
      }
      
      function draw_circle(center_x, center_y, radius){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        context.stroke();
      }
        
      function draw_line(center1_x, center1_y, center2_x, center2_y) {    
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(center1_x, center1_y);
        context.lineTo(center2_x, center2_y);
        context.stroke();
      }
        
      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
```

Input:

- **rel_x**, **rel_y** - relative position of player to the cannon
- **g** - gravity
- **init_v** - initial velocity of missile
- **trajectory** - set 1 or -1, will select one of two possible trajectories

Output:

- **dir_x**, **dir_y** - direction in which cannon should fire.

To get the solution, we need to solve the following system of equations:

```
x = v_x * t
y = v_y * t + g * t^2 / 2
```

We know, that v_x^2 + v_y^2 = init_v^2, so let's first express v_x and v_y:

```
v_x = x / t
v_y = y / t - g * t / 2
```

Then square them:

```
v_x^2 = x^2 * t^2
v_y^2 = y^2 / t^2 - y * g + g^2 * t^2 / 4
```

And sum them:

```
init_v^2 = (x^2 + y^2) / t^2 - y * g + g^2 * t^2 / 4
```

Know we can write a bisquare equation to find t:

```
g^2 * t^2 / 4 - y * g - init_v^2 + (x^2 + y^2) / t^2 = 0
```

Or:

```
g^2 * t^4 / 4 - y * g - init_v^2 * t^2 + (x^2 + y^2) = 0

a = g^2 / 4
b = - y * g - init_v^2
c = x^2 + y^2
D = b^2 - 4 * a * c
t^2 = (-b +-sqrt(D) ) / 2 / a
```

If *D < 0*, that means that the player is not reachable for the cannon.

So, once we know the time of flight, we can find v_x and v_y from initial equations:

```
v_x = x / t
v_y = y / t - g * t / 2
```

Comment: I was away from home and didn't expect anyone to answer, but you made my day. Good logic and good job, i'll redo it in my code and then mark it as answer.